# How to get the lights on edges

Tags: lighting

Im looking to get real world effect. I have attach this reference image what im looking for the final result.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to get it but did not get the result as per the reference images are. I cant get the lights on the edges as seen, And the image to center its glowing. Any suggestion or help with the real world. Thanks

**my result**

[image]

Comment: Is that frame something like this: https://www.dentalprimary.com/shop/crystal-led-frame/ ?

Comment: Edit: It seems to be from the geometry in the blend file. How accurate are your dimensions?